# Validate ASP NET API Token?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-membership, asp.net-authorization

**Background**

Visual Studio 2013, ASP NET WEB API 2

**Problem**

I am using the "standard" membership provider of .NET, but I need to have a custom login method. So I added a new method and then for me to generate the token I used this:

```
// Sign-in the user using the OWIN flow
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(Startup.OAuthOptions.AuthenticationType);
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName));
                // This is very important as it will be used to populate the current user id 
                // that is retrieved with the User.Identity.GetUserId() method inside an API Controller
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id, null, "LOCAL_AUTHORITY"));
                AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, new AuthenticationProperties());
                var currentUtc = new Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure.SystemClock().UtcNow;
                ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = currentUtc;
                ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = currentUtc.Add(new TimeSpan(14, 0, 0, 0));
                accesstoken = Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);
                Request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accesstoken);
                Authentication.SignIn(identity);
```

But when I try using this token given here in my client to consume some "Authorize" services. I'm getting a unathorized exception. How can I validate that the Token given here is valid.

And more over if it is not, how can I generate a valid one?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use AuthorizeAttributte i f you intend to use custom security flow.
like:

```
public class ApiAuthentication : AuthorizeAttribute
{
  protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext context)
  {
       //Your Authentication Logic Here for example:
       //context.Request.Headers.TryGetValues("Authorization", out buffers);
  }
}

protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
      //this method is for handling Unauthorized Request
}
```

then you can decorate your controller's method

```
[ApiAuthentication]        
[Queryable]
public IEnumerable<ProductIndex> GetProductIndex()
{
    // Return Data
}
```

*Cheers